# System configuration loop fields

Tags: magento2, system.xml, system-configuration

Do I need to list different fields for all websites in the system configuration? How can I do this?

I have 3 websites. And I want to list different fields with YesNo source.

```
<group id="websites" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
    <label>Websites Configuration</label>
    <field id="shop1" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0"> 
        <label>Website</label>
        <source_model>Model\Source\Websites</source_model>
    </field>
</group>
```

I need a loop field section.

```
public function toOptionArray()
{
   // TODO: Implement toOptionArray() method.

   $return = [];

   $run = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

   $storeManager = $run->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
   $websites = $storeManager->getWebsites();

   if (!empty($websites)) {
      foreach ($websites as $key => $value) {
          $return[$key] = [
              'label' => $value->getName(),
              'value' => $value->getId(),
          ];
       }
   }

   return $return;
}
```

Sorry, my English is not well.

Comment: Hi @Zalmoxis, Can you please explain a bit more in your question by editing your question?

Comment: I edited. Thanks.

Comment: Are those fields common for all websites/shops or each website can have different fileds?

Comment: Settings are global. I need only this.

Website 1 -> enable/disable
Website 2 -> enable/disable
Website 3 -> enable/disable